# Painting Over Wall Blemishes

Tags: drywall, painting, paint, primer, wallpaper

[Album First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B47Cz.jpg)

Background: I have some walls that were once covered in wallpaper and my wife and I removed them when we bought our house. We then casually patched and sanded some of the blemishes left by the wallpaper removal and painted the walls with some Behr paint that was a combined primer and paint.

I have come not be annoyed by what you see in the album, which I believe stems from my lack of prep, mainly knowledge about the best order to approach these things. Per the DIY guidelines I have done some research about what the proper order I should have followed while painting but many sources seem conflicting/personal preference.

Here are my main two questions.

- Is there anything I can do to fix the problems seen in the photos?
- When I paint my next room, would the following be an acceptable approach?

  1. [Seal Walls with this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OFHEG2)
  2. Skim Coat with Mud and sand
  3. [Prime With This](http://www.sherwin-williams.com/homeowners/products/catalog/multipurpose-primer/?referringCategory=interior-paint-coatings/primers/&N=759705555)
  4. Paint

If there are any resources that you have tried that show the correct way, I would appreciate that too, I can't tell the difference between most people's personal preference online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases the most successful and least time-consuming approach is to either remove and replace the drywall (and catch up with any issues exposed when the wall is open) or to lay a fresh layer of drywall on top of the wall that had wallpaper on it.

IMHO the skim coat of mud (sand optional) will do the job without any "special sealer" first, but it's a time consuming approach .vs. new drywall.

Comment: This is mainly in a hallway leading upstairs, so there would be a minimal benefit to removing the drywall completely. Do you think that if I sanded it down, mudded, sanded that back down, primed, and painted that it would look any better than before?

Comment: Appreciate the info, if you could answer my last comment it would help a lot. Thanks.